# Can I always find two new linear independent vectors whose dotproduct with existing vector \ge0 in vector space $R^4$

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

suppose V is 4-dimensional vector space,
$v_1$ and $v_2$ are linear independent in V,
now for arbitrary plane S that goes through origin,
can I find two new linear independent vector
in plane S that
condition:
\begin{align}
v_1 \cdot v_3  \ge 0 \ \& \ v_2 \cdot v_3  \ge0,
& v_1 \cdot v_4  \ge0 \ \& \ v_2 \cdot v_4  \ge0, \tag{1}
\end{align}
(i.e. the new vectors dotproduct with existing vectors always $\ge$0)
(I'm trying to be general, but basically I want $v_1$,$v_2$,$v_3$,$v_4$ to be linear independent,
with general S,$v_3$,$v_4$ should not be related to $v_1$,$v_2$,
and  $v_1$,$v_2$,$v_3$,$v_4$ spans V,
but say S1=span of {$v_1$,$v_2$}, and when S=S1, $v_3$,$v_4$ can be only be in S1,which is linear dependent on $v_1$,$v_2$, but under this special condition I still want to find linear independent $v_3$,$v_4$ that satisfy condition (1) so that the problem statement is a bit general.

If so, how to proof it,
If not so, is it because $v_1$ and $v_2$ have no constraint?
I'm thinking if $v_1 \cdot v_2 < 0$ might hinder the finding process,
If adding constraint $v_1 \cdot v_2 > 0$, can I always find $v_3$ and $v_4$
which satisfy condition (1)?

so question:

1.if $v_1$ and $v_2$ have no constraint, can I always find $v_3$ and $v_4$

2.If $v_1 \cdot v_2 > 0$, can I always find $v_3$ and $v_4$

Answer (score 1):

Take any vector $u$ orthogonal to both $v_1$ and $v_2$ and a vector $w$ in the plane spanned by $v_1$ and $v_2$ so that $w\cdot v_1<0$ and $w\cdot v_2>0$. Now let $S$ be spanned by $u$ and $w$. Any vector $au+bw$ in $S$ has $v_1\cdot (au+bw)=bv_1\cdot w<0$ and $v_2\cdot (au+bw)=bv_2\cdot w>0$ (if $b>0$, in the case $b<0$ the inequalities are the other way). This shows that $v_3$ and $v_4$ both need $b=0$ and then they are not linearly independent.

Comment: You cant, this is a counterexample for the claim that you can do this for arbitrary S.

Comment: I see, sorry, I hadn’t read the answer properly; I deleted my comment.